# Finding/replacing a regex pattern within a string between two marker strings

Tags: regex, perl, awk, sed, command-line

It's not so much the regex *pattern* as it is *how* to achieve it. I've attempted perl, sed, and awk (various attempts with each), but I'm not sure how possible this is as a one-liner (I'd prefer to not write a perl script).

Say I have

```
#MARKER_TOP
INSERT INTO ('col1', 'col2', 'col3')
VALUES
(123,123,'2018-20-20 24:24:24',123)
...etc.
(123,123,'2018-20-20 24:24:24',123);
#MARKER_BOTTOM

...and more! (not all INSERT tables will be marked, btw)
```

What I'd like to do is replace all those string dates with SQLs `NOW()`. Specifically, with Perl, I've tried the following:

`perl -w -pi.bak -e "undef $/; s/(#MARKER_TOP.*)'[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]'(.*#MARKER_BOTTOM)/$1 NOW() $2/msg" test.sql`

But it's ripping all of the blocks of interest (`#MARKER_TOP`, etc.) out completely and replacing it with `NOW()` which is way too heavy-handed for what I'm wanting.

Comment: What do you mean by "not all INSERT tables will be marked"?

Comment: I mean some of those SQL statements (i.e. `INSERT INTO...`) will not have the markers (`MARKER_TOP, MARKER_BOTTOM`), this file is thousands of lines long with multiple `INSERT` statements. Those which do not have the markers, should not have the dates changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `awk` like this:

```
awk '/#MARKER_TOP/{m=1} /#MARKER_BOTTOM/{m=0} m{
   gsub(/\047[0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{2}){2} [0-9]{2}(:[0-9]{2}){2}\047/, "NOW()")} 1' file

#MARKER_TOP
INSERT INTO ('col1', 'col2', 'col3')
VALUES
(123,123,NOW(),123)
...etc.
(123,123,NOW(),123);
#MARKER_BOTTOM
```

Here is how it works:

- `/#MARKER_TOP/{m=1}` : set a flag `m=1` when we get text `#MARKER_TOP`
- `/#MARKER_BOTTOM/{m=0}` : reset flag `m=0` when we get text `#MARKER_BOTTOM`
- `m{gsub(/.../, "NOW()")}` : when `m==1` then replace date string with `NOW()` using regex
- `1` : print each record

Comment: Nice, but I assume the enclosing `'` should be removed too. On a side note, Mawk doesn't support `{n}`.

Comment: ok thanks, corrected single quote issue. Hope OP is not using `mawk` otherwise regex will have to change as well.

Comment: @anubhava That works beautifully. Would you mind explaining it (briefly)? I'm not _that_ familiar with `awk`. THANKS!

Comment: Sure, I've added explanation in answer. `\047` is octal for single quote.

Comment: @anubhava What would the difference be if I wanted to write this back to the file, replacing those changed sections?

Comment: If you have gnu awk then use: `awk -i inplace '/#MARKER_TOP/{m=1} /#MARKER_BOTTOM/{m=0} m{gsub(/\047[0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{2}){2} [0-9]{2}(:[0-9]{2}){2}\047/, "NOW()")} 1' file` otherwise use old fashioned: `awk '...' file > _tmp.out && mv _tmp.out file`

Comment: @anubhava Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

A simple way is to use the [range operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators)

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $file = 'test.sql';
open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";

my $re_date = qr/'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}'/;

while (<$fh>) 
{
    if (/#MARKER_TOP/ .. /#MARKER_BOTTOM/) {
        s/$re_date/NOW()/;
    }   

    print;
}
```

or in a one-liner

```
perl -wpe"s/'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}'/NOW()/ 
    if /#MARKER_TOP/ .. /#MARKER_BOTTOM/
" test.sql
```

where I delimit the code with `"..."` so to be able to use `'` inside (there are other ways).

I assume that there is a single date on a line, in the format strictly as given in the question, inside `''`.  I tested by adding another `INSERT` section but without markers. The replacements happen only in the markers-bracketed one.

---

The range operator works by keeping the state: once its left operand turns true it becomes true, and it stays true until the right operand turns true, after which it returns false in the next iteration.  It works this way in scalar context, while in list context it returns a list within that range. See linked docs.